# Error getting information from related entities - JAVA, SPRINGBOOT, JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-2

I hope you are well and can help me with a problem.
I leave my initial code parts here:

**Product Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "products")

public class ProductEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String brand;
private String description;
private String price;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private ProductCategoryEntity category;
private String stock;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ProductCommentsEntity> productComments;

}
```

**Category Product Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "categories")
public class ProductCategoryEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ProductEntity> products;

public ProductCategoryEntity(Long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Comments Product Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "comments")
public class ProductCommentsEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String tittle;
private String comment;
private Integer rating;
private Date date;
@ManyToOne
private UserEntity user;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
@JsonIgnore
private ProductEntity product;

}
```

So using JPA, Java and Spring Boot Repositories, I want to implement this **method**:

```
@Override
public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
    List<ProductEntity> productsEntity = this.productRepositoryJpa.findAll();
    return this.objectConverter.converterToTypeList(productsEntity, Product.class);
}
```

But then I get the following **error**:

In Postman this appears: `Error: Transferred a partial file`

and in the Intellij console the following appears:

```
2023-10-23 17:50:02.975  INFO 10556 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
Hibernate: select productent0_.id as id1_5_, productent0_.brand as brand2_5_, productent0_.category_id as category7_5_, productent0_.description as descript3_5_, productent0_.name as name4_5_, productent0_.price as price5_5_, productent0_.stock as stock6_5_ from products productent0_
Hibernate: select productcat0_.id as id1_2_0_, productcat0_.name as name2_2_0_ from categories productcat0_ where productcat0_.id=?
Hibernate: select products0_.category_id as category7_5_0_, products0_.id as id1_5_0_, products0_.id as id1_5_1_, products0_.brand as brand2_5_1_, products0_.category_id as category7_5_1_, products0_.description as descript3_5_1_, products0_.name as name4_5_1_, products0_.price as price5_5_1_, products0_.stock as stock6_5_1_ from products products0_ where products0_.category_id=?
Hibernate: select productcom0_.product_id as product_6_3_0_, productcom0_.id as id1_3_0_, productcom0_.id as id1_3_1_, productcom0_.comment as comment2_3_1_, productcom0_.date as date3_3_1_, productcom0_.product_id as product_6_3_1_, productcom0_.rating as rating4_3_1_, productcom0_.tittle as tittle5_3_1_, productcom0_.user_id as user_id7_3_1_, userentity1_.id as id1_7_2_, userentity1_.city as city2_7_2_, userentity1_.country as country3_7_2_, userentity1_.extra_information as extra_in4_7_2_, userentity1_.number as number5_7_2_, userentity1_.postal_code as postal_c6_7_2_, userentity1_.street as street7_7_2_, userentity1_.creation_date as creation8_7_2_, userentity1_.email as email9_7_2_, userentity1_.identification_card as identif10_7_2_, userentity1_.last_name as last_na11_7_2_, userentity1_.name as name12_7_2_, userentity1_.password as passwor13_7_2_, userentity1_.phone as phone14_7_2_, userentity1_.role_id as role_id16_7_2_, userentity1_.state as state15_7_2_, roleentity2_.id as id1_6_3_, roleentity2_.name as name2_6_3_ from comments productcom0_ left outer join users userentity1_ on productcom0_.user_id=userentity1_.id left outer join roles roleentity2_ on userentity1_.role_id=roleentity2_.id where productcom0_.product_id=?
2023-10-23 17:50:03.212  WARN 10556 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure while trying to resolve exception [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.checkCommitted(ResponseFacade.java:529) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:362) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.sendServerError(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:552) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleHttpMessageNotWritable(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:442) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:209) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:142) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1332) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1143) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1790) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2023-10-23 17:50:03.220 ERROR 10556 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.co.latienda.domain.model.Product["productCategory"]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.ProductCategory["products"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.Product["productCategory"]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.Product["productCategory"]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.ProductCategory["products"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.Product["productCategory"]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.ProductCategory["products"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.Product["productCategory"]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.ProductCategory["products"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.Product["productCategory"]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.ProductCategory["products"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.Product["productCategory"]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.ProductCategory["products"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.Product["productCategory"]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.ProductCategory["products"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.Product["productCategory"]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.ProductCategory["products"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.Product["productCategory"]->com.co.latienda.domain.model.Product["productCategory"])] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:789) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
```

**NOTE:** I tried to solve it with several solutions that I saw on the internet, I already used the one from `@JsonIgnore` and the other `@Json` annotations that they put on the identities.

I also leave some possibly *relevant information here*.

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.16'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.co'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
}

configurations {
compileOnly {
    extendsFrom annotationProcessor
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:3.2.0'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I already tried solutions with Spring annotations, such as `@JsonIgnore` or the others suggested by @Json....
I implemented DTOS, but it was not good enough to solve the problem.

I'm hoping to find a way to fix this bidirectionally related entities issue.

Comment: You are using a DTO and have the JSON ignore on your entity, that is pretty much pointless. The `@JsonIgnore` / `@JsonBackRefernce` needs to be on the object that is being serialized. Finally don't use `@Data` for entities as that is a bad idea, why see https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/

Comment: I tried to put the @Json to the models and not to the entities and it worked, the problem I would have is that in the architecture I am using, the models should not have spring annotations to decouple them from everything

Comment: `@JsonIgnore` isn't a spring annotation but a jackson one. Also those rules/guidelines only make things complicated it basically is the same as we want to use JPA but not use any of the annotations (altrhough strictly speaking you could do all mapping in XML but that is also true for Spring configuration).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is because you have a circular reference in your mappings that are not being excluded.

That would be, ProductCategoryEntity has a list of ProductEntity, which has a ProductCategoryEntity which has a list of ProductEntity.....

The best way to handle these is to use @JsonBackReference and @JsonManagedReference.

On your `ProductCategoryEntity`

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ProductEntity> products;
```

On your `ProductEntity`

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private ProductCategoryEntity category;
```

See the documentation for these annotations [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/latest/index.html)

Comment: Hello, I had already tried that solution and it didn't work, I just tried it but it doesn't work either, the same error keeps coming up, I'll show you a part of the error because it's the same message cyclically.

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Comment: Also implement: @ JsonIdentityInfo and @ JsonIdentityReference and it doesn't work